# Why is return keyword needed in array.map when returning an object with arrow function?

Tags: typescript

Why do we have to write `return` keyword within rawApiData.map callback arrow function in this case?

```js
protected assembleLCodeDealers(rawApiData): DealerLossCodeDealer[] {
    if (rawApiData) {
      return rawApiData.map(p => {
        return {
          code: p.code,
          id: p.id,
          name: p.name
        } as DealerLossCodeDealer;
      });
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm confused about the question, do you not know how `map` works? Or are you confused about the syntax of arrow functions?

Comment: As indicated by the typing, `assembleLCodeDealers` is expected to yield an array, so it has to return an array. If there's a case where it "does nothing", it will have to return an empty array instead of the usual "just return nothing so that it yields undefined"

Comment: I need to understand why we have to write return before rawApiData.map in this case.

Comment: Because otherwise the `assembleLCodeDealers` function doesn't return anything, which the typing says it _must_ do. `Array.map` creates a new array, and that's all it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be confused by the [arrow function shorthand syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#basic_syntax) with 1 returned expression, which indeed does not need an explicit `return`.

But if you use curly braces, it opens a code block for multiple expressions, not an object to be returned.

Simply wrap the curly braces of the object to be returned with parentheses, to avoid them from being interpreted as a code block:

```js
rawApiData.map(p => ({
  code: p.code,
  id: p.id,
  name: p.name
}) as DealerLossCodeDealer)
```

See the [advanced syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#advanced_syntax)